# How can I add another modal to my add modal component without getting "JSX expressions must have one parent element. error"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to define another modal to my add modal but I get JSX expressions must have one parent element.

```
export default class AddModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    showAddModal = () => {
        this.refs.myModal.open();
    }

    render() {
        return( 
            <Modal ref={"myModal"}
                   style={{ ...
             </Modal>  
              // till this part everything is ok

             <Modal ref={"anotherModal"}> // I want to this but I can't
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you must have only one parent element inside the `render()` method.

Just wrap everything under a `View` component, so your `render()` method would look like:

```
    render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Modal ref={"myModal"}>
            </Modal>  
            <Modal ref={"anotherModal"}>
            </Modal>
          </View>
        );
      }
```

Comment: You still have to implement the logic properly. Try using the props `visible` in your modal components and use a state variable to manage it. Something like `<Modal ref={"myModal"} visible={this.state.isAnotherModalVisible}></Modal> ` and in your state `state = { isAnotherModalVisible: true }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `React.Fragment`
https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Something like this (short syntax example)

```
<>
 <Modal ref={"myModal"}></Modal>
 <Modal ref={"anotherModal"}></Modal>
</>
```